# Adding a legend to a matplotlib boxplot with multiple plots on same axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a boxplot generated with matplotlib:

[image]

However, I have no idea how to generate the legend. Whenever I try the following I get an error saying `Legend does not support {boxes: ...` I've done a fair bit of searching and there doesn't seem to be an example showing how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated!

```
bp1 = ax.boxplot(data1, positions=[1,4], notch=True, widths=0.35, patch_artist=True)
bp2 = ax.boxplot(data2, positions=[2,5], notch=True, widths=0.35, patch_artist=True)

ax.legend([bp1, bp2], ['A', 'B'], loc='upper right')
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [`boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html) returns a dictionary of artists

> result : dict
> A dictionary mapping each component of the boxplot to a list of the matplotlib.lines.Line2D instances created. That dictionary has the following keys (assuming vertical boxplots):
>
> - `boxes`: the main body of the boxplot showing the quartiles and the median’s confidence intervals if enabled.
> - [...]

Using the  `boxes`, you can get the legend artists as

```
ax.legend([bp1["boxes"][0], bp2["boxes"][0]], ['A', 'B'], loc='upper right')
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

data1=np.random.randn(40,2)
data2=np.random.randn(30,2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bp1 = ax.boxplot(data1, positions=[1,4], notch=True, widths=0.35, 
                 patch_artist=True, boxprops=dict(facecolor="C0"))
bp2 = ax.boxplot(data2, positions=[2,5], notch=True, widths=0.35, 
                 patch_artist=True, boxprops=dict(facecolor="C2"))

ax.legend([bp1["boxes"][0], bp2["boxes"][0]], ['A', 'B'], loc='upper right')

ax.set_xlim(0,6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Strange that this code didn't work for me. I wonder whether something happened with a version of pyplot. The legend shows up but there's nothing inside it. It seems that `legend()` clears it out.

Comment: @ChrisA. Sorry, there was of course one `ax.legend` too much in the code. Corrected that.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, do you know how can I change the '2' and '5' labels? Like putting the name of the variable being presented or anything like this

Comment: @dekio: this is done by `ax.set_xticklabels(['A', 'B'])`

Answer (score 4):

Just as a complement to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's response, if you are plotting in a for loop like this:

```
for data in datas:
    ax.boxplot(data, positions=[1,4], notch=True, widths=0.35, 
             patch_artist=True, boxprops=dict(facecolor="C0"))
```

You cannot save the plots as variables. So in that case, create legend labels list `legends`, append the plots into another list `elements` and use list comprehension to put a legend for each of them:

```
labels = ['A', 'B']
colors = ['blue', 'red']
elements = []

for data, color in zip(datas, colors):
    elements.append(ax.boxplot(data, positions=[1,4], notch=True,\
    widths=0.35, patch_artist=True, boxprops=dict(facecolor=color)))

ax.legend([element["boxes"][0] for element in elements], labels)
```