# Matplotlib boxplot legend without using ax

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way of creating boxplot legend in matplotlib without using the return value of `ax.boxplot()` as in [Adding a legend to a matplotlib boxplot with multiple plots on same axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528955/adding-a-legend-to-a-matplotlib-boxplot-with-multiple-plots-on-same-axes)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 480
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))
for i, frame in zip(range(ts.index.dayofyear.nunique()), 
                        ts.index.dayofyear.unique()):
    plt.boxplot(ts[ts.index.dayofyear == frame], positions=[i], widths=0.9)
```

Above is just toy example code. In my project I actually call `plt.boxplot()` in the separate function each time (several calls of the function but the same axis is used) and I do not want to make  any new return and parameter values.

Is there a way to create a legend for boxplots without using those return values as in other types of plots (by passing `label=...`)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Pandas series, consider a Pandas plot solution that still interfaces with matplotlib. You will need to first upcast series to a data frame and assign needed *hour* and *day* indicator columns. With this approach, you can pass `ax` object as an argument and use that for additional needs or use defaults with [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
# CONVERT TO DATA FRAME WITH day AND hour COLUMNS
ts_df = (ts.to_frame()
           .rename({0:'value'}, axis='columns')
           .assign(hour = lambda x: x.index.hour,
                   dayofyear = lambda x: x.index.dayofyear)
        )

ts_df.head()            
#                         value  hour  dayofyear
# 2014-02-01 00:00:00 -0.555308     0         32
# 2014-02-01 01:00:00  0.720157     1         32
# 2014-02-01 02:00:00 -1.140971     2         32
# 2014-02-01 03:00:00 -0.359197     3         32
# 2014-02-01 04:00:00 -2.241330     4         32

seaborn.set()
for i, g in ts_df.groupby(['dayofyear']):
    myfig, myaxes = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,4))
    g['value'].plot(kind = 'box', ax = myaxes, 
                        title = 'Hourly Value Boxplot in Day {}'.format(i))
    # myaxes.legend(...)

    plt.show()
```

[image: First Plot Output]

Alternatively, if you need all boxplots in one plot, [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the data for day columns:

```
ts_pvt_df = ts_df.pivot(index='hour', columns = 'dayofyear', values = 'value')

seaborn.set()
myfig, myaxes = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))
ts_pvt_df.plot(kind = 'box', ax = myaxes, title = 'Hourly Value Boxplots by Day')

plt.show()
```

[image: Second Plot Output]

Comment: I need it as a *legend*, not as a title. There is no problem to set up the title even without using pandas. I have multiple plots on the same figure, so the title/ylabel is not an option.

Comment: I do not understand. Can you screenshot an image of desired output (even if needing to use image software)?