# No handle with lables to put in legend error while plotting box plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am plotting a box plot, and here is my code. and I need to show legends at outside the box plot. The legend should be the column names in my data However, in my code, i am using this code line

```
plt.legend(title='column labels', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

but it gives this "No handle with lables to put in legend"

I want to show legend like this figure

[image]

my data looks like this

[image]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataframe = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Downloads/mydata.csv')
print(dataframe.head())

```
#df1=dataframe[:20]
df1 = dataframe[dataframe.columns[range(50)]]
# Creating axes instance
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
#df1.boxplot(grid='false', color='blue',fontsize=10, rot=30, widths = 0.6 ) 
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(20, 10))
#plt.legend()

plt.legend(title='column labels', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,0), loc="lower left")
# Creating plot
plt.boxplot(df1)
 
# show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you will find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528955/adding-a-legend-to-a-matplotlib-boxplot-with-multiple-plots-on-same-axes/65237307) helpful.

Comment: can you provide a bit more detail about the plot or the data frame? From your code, it seems like there is only 1 boxplot per column

Comment: HI I updated the question and included a screenshot of my data .. yes i have one boxplot per column. I used figure for reference that i want to show legend slike this outside the box plot