# Improve Matplotlib legend for boxplots by showing patches instead of lines

Tags: matplotlib

The legend for `plt.boxplot` entries appear as a thin line as opposed to a rectangular patch. How do I change the legend such that it displays patches instead of thin lines as seen in the figure below? For simplicity, I have added a minimum reproducible case below.

[image: boxplot_bad_legend]

To reproduce,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jun 25 01:42:14 2021

@author: rsk3900
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = 5*np.random.rand(100, 1)
B = 10*np.random.rand(100, 1) -5
C = 7*np.random.rand(100, 1) - 5

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
bp0 = axs.boxplot(A, positions=[0], patch_artist=True)
bp1 = axs.boxplot(B, positions=[1], patch_artist=True)
bp2 = axs.boxplot(C, positions=[2], patch_artist=True)

colors = ['pink', 'lightblue', 'darkgreen']
for bplot, color in zip((bp0, bp1, bp2), colors):
    for patch in bplot['boxes']:
        patch.set_facecolor(color)

axs.legend(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

The solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274981/can-i-make-a-plot-legend-show-box-plots-using-matplotlib) does not work. The proposed class fails to accept boxplot objects (which is essentially a dictionary of LinePlots and Patches).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a legend to a matplotlib boxplot with multiple plots on same axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528955/adding-a-legend-to-a-matplotlib-boxplot-with-multiple-plots-on-same-axes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a box in the legend, you can do the following.

```
axs.legend([bp0["boxes"][0], bp1["boxes"][0], bp2["boxes"][0]], ['A', 'B', 'C'], loc='upper right')
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. So if I understand, previously it iterate through the keys and settled on the Lines2D artist as opposed to the patch artists? I have made a new issue on their GIT to fix this as default behavior over [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20512#issuecomment-868242955).

Comment: If you check the contents of bp0, you will see that it is a patch. `bp0：{...,'boxes': [<matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x184ff68df98>],...}`